# Django REST framework: Basic Auth without debug

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, basic-authentication, debug-mode

Got a problem with **Basic authentication** in **Django REST framework** when **debug mode** is **turned off**. I am using Django 1.8.4 and Django REST Framework 3.2.2.

Looks like it saves credentials for all computers with the same IP address when the first is logged in. But after some time it prompts for the username and password again.

However, this problem does not occur when the debug mode in Django REST framework settings is set to *True*. I would like to have the same behaviour when debug is turned off. What is causing the problem?

Answer (score 3):

In settings.py file add the host/domain-name of the system to which django is allowed to serve.

Use:

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']` or `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']` so that django can serve the localhost.

You may also add other IP address as you wish.

Example:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '192.1.12.23']
```

Domain names can also be accepted:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.example.com']
```

If you wish to serve many hosts, you may simply use *, as shown:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

This will serve Django to any host in the world.

Comment: I have my domain-name of the system in ALLOWED_HOST setting. And it does not work. Even when changed to ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] it does not work either.

Comment: are you talking about simple login by username and password, when you say problem on basic authentication?

Comment: Can you provide the Source Code (with requirements.txt) ?

Comment: Here is the important code (since I can't provide the full):  http://pastebin.com/UfSgx31M

Comment: are you using django sessions for login?

Comment: Yes, `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware`. Deleting the session entries from the django_session table doesn't help. Session timetout to zero neither. Probably it is saving sessions somewhere else and using that one.

Comment: will you please check where is it saving session and let me know, also let me know if you need help finding where the session is stored

Comment: Can't find any information where exactly it is saving, because it looks like Django does it automatically. No change in configuration helped it. In case the debug mode is true, it somehow does not save the session, because it works

Comment: Do you have a Apache /nginx server running in front of django?

Comment: Yes, but it also does not work on a Django development server on localhost, so I do not think that is the problem